# Retrieve JSON values from ejs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to node and ejs, I have below code, and need to know how to get the values from EJs file to post it to mongoDB

EJS file

```
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="username"> Username </label>
        <input type="text" for="username"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password"> Password </label>
        <input type="password" for="password" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email"> Email </label>
        <input type="text" for="email"/>
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button> 
</form>
```

JS file

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){

      var item = $('form input');
      var user = [{username:item.val()},{password:item.val()},{email:item.val()}];

      console.log(user);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/register',
        data: user,
        success: function(data){
          //do something with the data via front-end framework
            console.log(data);
          location.reload();
        }
      });

      return false;

  });
```

As of now when I insert to mongo DB I get a new uuid but the values are going in as `"0"`

please aasist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the line `var item = $('form input');` is actually a collection of each input, while the line `var user = [{username:item.val()},{password:item.val()},{email:item.val()}];` is only grabbing the value of the first one (this is because of how jQuery can appear to hide a collection), instead I would try this (assuming you wanted to grab specific values out of that form):

```
var items = $('form');
var user = {
      username: $('[name=username]', items).val(),
      password: $('[name=password]', items).val(),
      email: $('[name=email]', items).val()
    };
```

With following change to your html

```
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="input-username"> Username </label>
        <input type="text" id="input-username" name="username"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="input-password"> Password </label>
        <input type="password" id="input-password" name="password" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="input-email"> Email </label>
        <input type="text" id="input-email" name="email"/>
    </p>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button> 
</form>
```

Also the `for` attribute in the `<label>` element is to associate with an `<input>` that has an `id` attribute with the same value.  So considering that `id`s should be unique and only resolve to a single element I would suggest adding some kind of name spacing like `input-` to them.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it really helped